# Streaming Stores Segmentation Fault on Intel MIC

Tags: intel-mic

I want to implement streaming stores in my code on Intel MIC. I have a force_array and 3 variables tempx, tempy and tempz. I need to do some computation and then store them in another array which won't be used in near future. So I felt streaming stores would be a better choice to improve the performance. But I see that I am getting a segmentation fault and I am not sure if it is because of the load or the store. This code is preceded and succeeded by a few lines of code and the entire piece of code is inside two for loops which is preceded by openmp directives. As it is a parallel program, I am not able to debug it well. Can anyone help me by finding out the mistake(s) ?

Thanks in advance !!! The code is given below:

```
    for(k=0;k<np;k++)    //np is the number of particles.
    {
      for(j=k+1;j<np;j++)
      {
        __m512d y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6;

        y1 = _mm512_load_pd(force_array + k*nd + 0);
        y4 = _mm512_load_pd(&tempx);
        y1 = _mm512_sub_pd(y1,y4);

        y2 = _mm512_load_pd(force_array + k*nd + 1);
        y5 = _mm512_load_pd(&tempy);
        y2 = _mm512_sub_pd(y2,y5);

        y3 = _mm512_load_pd(force_array + k*nd + 2);
        y6 = _mm512_load_pd(&tempz);
        y3 = _mm512_sub_pd(y3,y6);

        _mm512_storenr_pd((f+k*nd+0), y1);
        _mm512_storenr_pd((f+k*nd+1), y2);
        _mm512_storenr_pd((f+k*nd+2), y3);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that force_array is a double and tempx, tempy and tempz are also doubles.

Comment: Have you checked that all of your loads will be aligned on 64 bytes boundaries?  _mm512_load_pd requires 64 byte alignment.

Comment: Also, to help you debug this you can make one thread enter an infinite loop based on its thread id. (like if (thread_id == 0) { temp = 5; while(temp==5) { printf("debug me"); } } )  and then set the debugger to break in the loop, and set the value of temp to something else.  Then you can step through the code in a single thread.

Comment: I have used __assume_aligned(f,64);__assume_aligned(force_array,64);
for 64 byte alignment where f is the array in which the store has to take place. Also I used  _mm_malloc ( nd * np * sizeof ( double ),64); while creating the f array and double force_array[np*nd] __attribute__((aligned(64))); for creating the force_array. I think I have taken care of the 64 byte boundaries. Is this okay ?

Comment: I have found attribute aligned to be unreliable at times for stack objects (i.e. your force array) , the exact reason escapes me at the moment. Add an assertion test of each pointer at run time by checking the address mod 64 == 0.

Comment: Also, is nd a multiple of 8?

Comment: I am not able to add the assertion test for the force_array. The compiler is throwing an error.
 error: expression must have integral type
    __assume(&force_array%64 == 0);
Also, nd is 3 not a multiple of 8. Should I make it a multiple of 8? The force_array is of size np\*nd. So for np=1000, nd = 3, np*nd = 3000 is a multiple of 8. Will it still cause any problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_mm512_load_pd()` requires the address that you are loading from to be 64 byte aligned.

The arrays `f` and `force_array` will need to have their starting addresses 64 byte aligned and allocated with `_mm_alloc(size,64)` or be declared `__attribute__((aligned(64))` for stack objects as you have done.

I think the problem here is not the starting addresses but the computed addresses during your inner loop.  If `nd=3` that means when `k=1` the offset from the beginning of the `force_array` with be 3 doubles i.e. 24 bytes.

You will need to pad each of these force objects out to 8 bytes to use aligned loads, otherwise you will need to use unaligned loads.

Best regards,

Alastair

P.S. y1 and y2 load 8 doubles that are only 8 bytes apart, are you sure this is what you meant to achieve?

Comment: Ya you said right that the problem is in the computed addresses. I need a 64-byte alignment. The force_array contains np*nd elements where nd is the number of dimensions (here nd=3 - x,y,z). As I am using a packed load, it loads 8 doubles at a time. But as nd=3, I need either 9 or else 6. As 9 is not possible, I need to load 6 doubles so that all 3 dimensions are considered for 2 elements. In such a case, I have to pad after every 6 doubles for 64 byte alignment. An array can’t be padded as it is stored contiguously. ...( continued in the next comment)

Comment: So we need to think about structure of arrays (SOA). Now my question is how to declare the structure of arrays so that only 6 doubles are loaded at a time - x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2.